# Run gsettings with crontab

Tags: cron, python3, desktop-background, gsettings

I've made a simple *python* script to change my wallpaper (Ubuntu **18.04**) by randomly taking an image in a specific folder. I use **gsettings** command. It works when I run it manually, but I want to automate it with **crontab**.

I had the following error because crontab hasn't all variables I had when I run my script manually:

```
(process:xxxxx): dconf-WARNING **: 15:07:01.547: failed to commit changes to dconf: Impossible de lancer automatiquement D-Bus sans $DISPLAY X11
```

So I found some solutions like :

```
dbus_session_bus_address = 'PID=$(pgrep gnome-session | head -n1) && export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(grep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$PID/environ|cut -d= -f2-) && '

command = dbus_session_bus_address + 'gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri ' + getRandomImage()
```

It seems work for most people but I have a problem, my crontab hasn't permissions :

```
grep: /proc/$pid/environ: Permission denied
dconf-WARNING **: 15:19:01.514: failed to commit changes to dconf: The address indicated is empty
```

So I run the script with `sudo crontab -e`, but I have the following error :

```
dconf-WARNING **: 15:22:01.807: failed to commit changes to dconf: Connection is closed
```

Also, I prefer use my user crontab.. What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Are you actually using your user crontab (`crontab -e`) or root's (`sudo crontab -e`)? I wouldn't be surprised if the latter resulted in a permission error, since `/proc/$pid/environ` should only be readable by `$pid`'s owner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to steeldriver's comment, I found the solution !

Actually, the `pgrep gnome-session` command gives me 2 PID.
When I `ls -l /proc/`, I can see the first pid directory belongs to *gdm* (Gnome Display Manager), and the second belongs to my user.

So in my script, I just replace `PID=$(pgrep gnome-session | head -n1)` by `PID=$(pgrep gnome-session | tail -n1)` to use the PID associate to my user.

I don't know if this solution (with `tail -n1`) can work for everyone. I think the best thing to do is to run the `pgrep gnome-session` command, look at the owner of pid folders, and choose the one that belongs to our user.

Hoping that it will be useful !